# How to preserve scrolling of centered image in case of small display

Tags: css, css-position

I have login form, where the logo is at the top of it and whole form is centered on the screen. Everything works perfectly but when I try it on small display, where this form does not fit vertically, logo is cropped and I can not scroll at the top of it.

Simplyfied example is here:

```css
.login-form {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  width: 80px;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-form">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/logo-tv-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
  </div>

  <form class="form-container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
    
    <button>Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I tried to position that login form also with flex instead of transform translate, but with the same result. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution with flex in the end. That problem was caused by transform rule.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.centered-box {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.login-form {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  width: 80px;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered-box">
  <div class="login-form">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/logo-tv-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
    </div>

    <form class="form-container">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password">

      <button>Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use for small screens (using media queries):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .login-form {
        top: 0;
        transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    }
}
```

Please replace "768px" with the screen width you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to PREVENT Scroll Vertically then only this answer is useful for you: I have added only bellow 2 class:

```
/* You can Change the width of small device screen you expected */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
   .logo {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 30vh;/*Adjust it as per your logo size*/
    min-width: 15vw; /*Adjust it as per your logo size*/
}
.img-container {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
text-align:center;
    }



    .login-form {
      width: 250px;
      background-color: #eee;
      padding: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .logo {
      width: 100%;
      max-height: 
    }

    .img-container {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      text-align:center;
    }

    .form-container {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .button {
      width: 80px;
    }

    input {
      width: 200px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
/* You can Change the width of small device screen you expected */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .logo {
      width: auto;
      max-height: 30vh;
      min-width: 15vw;
    }
}
    <div class="login-form">
      <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/logo-tv-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
      </div>

      <form class="form-container">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
        
        <button>Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```